# Possible network bootstrap error, with inappropriate error message

Tags: corda

I am generating node configs for 3 different nodes using the enterprise version of network bootstrapper 3.2. I have 3 different abc_node.conf in a directory.

What I am observing is that, network-bootstrap works fine if it has to generate configs for **1 or 2** nodes. If it is **3** or more it is failing with the following error.

```
Bootstrapping local test network in /root/finance
Found the following CorDapps: []
Generating node directory for agra
Generating node directory for bangalore
Generating node directory for chennai
Nodes found in the following sub-directories: [agra, bangalore, chennai]
Waiting for all nodes to generate their node-info files...
... still waiting. If this is taking longer than usual, check the node logs.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in /root/finance/chennai/logs.
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.generateNodeInfo(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:112)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion.access$generateNodeInfo(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:71)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfos$1$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:95)
        at net.corda.nodeapi.internal.network.NetworkBootstrapper$Companion$generateNodeInfos$1$1.invoke(NetworkBootstrapper.kt:71)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.ValueOrException$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:140)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.OpenFuture$DefaultImpls.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImpl.capture(CordaFutureImpl.kt:152)
        at net.corda.core.internal.concurrent.CordaFutureImplKt$fork$$inlined$also$lambda$1.run(CordaFutureImpl.kt:32)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in /root/finance/bangalore/logs.
                ... 11 more
        Suppressed: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error while generating node info file. Please check the logs in /root/finance/agra/logs.
                ... 11 more
```

The node info logs for these looks totally fine, without any errors.

Also, when I try to generate the node configs for 1 or 2 nodes, it will generate it successfully without any issues.

**So, is this related to time-out? If so, can we specify the timeout value while bootstrapping?**

Comment: Or is it okay if I generate node configs individually, and then copy it to appropriate nodes? Would this work?

Comment: [UPDATE]: After the above step, the node configs were partially generated. But the node folders were missing network_parameter and additional_node_infos. I copied this manually to all the nodes, then booted the cordapp.. it came up just fine. Serves the purpose now. But still the bootstrapper command should have done the job, which is failing currently!

Comment: Can you post the logs anyway? What has and has not been printed to the logs will give us an indication of the point at which bootstrapping fails.

Comment: Hi @Joel posting two links for two log files that is generated for "bangalore" node. The other nodes have similar outputs. Let me know if you need anything else apart from this. [node-info-gen.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1ZXsTirVBtAM4NBbqT5H4FmzbNcrH_nbV) [node-localhost.localdomain.log](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Gr_Mk2stz8KRqULOJ11KaYHIU71LmhIo)

Comment: But those are the logs of a successful node - what about the Chennai node that failed?

Comment: Hi Joel, If you observe the error above again.. last 4 lines specifically, even Chennai and Agra have failed. So all three have failed, and all 3 have similar logs like the one i have already posted.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you that something has gone wrong with the node-info generation, not the bootstrapping process.

This is usually related to machine setup.

Check: [IllegalStateException Error while generating node info files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52623723/illegalstateexception-error-while-generating-node-info-files/) and see if changing to urandom helps.